# Remove unnecessary HTTP headers in POST request using rest assured

Tags: java, http, http-headers, rest-assured

When I submit my HTTP POST request, I see headers that I did not expect (highlighted):

***Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: none,gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1**
SSL-Client-CN: POS-1234-1234
**Host: 123.123.123.123:8081
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_312)***

How can i remove them?

```
    @Test
    public HeaderConfig sampleTest() {
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/local.properties")) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);
            
            RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("RestAssured.baseURI");
            RestAssured.port =  Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("RestAssured.port"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        String test1 = "some string data";

       Response response = given().header("SSL-Client-CN","POS-1234-1234").body(hexStringToByteArray(test1)).when().post().then().using().extract().response();
        
        String body = response.getBody().asString();
        int status = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
        Assert.assertEquals(status, 200);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Don't see anything that produces your request header. Please add correct code part .

Comment: The problem is that I do not set any headers in the code, however, they are sent in the request. As I understand it, this is a certain set of default headers that rest assured initializes

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, i added en example in my "post request" code part

Comment: I guess `body(hexStringToByteArray(test1))` produces these headers. Since you want to send as `Byte[]` --> Content-Type must be `application/octet-stream` with default charset `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Others header do NO harms.